# The Meta Split's effect on earning Quorum and Convention badges

Tags: support, badges, meta

Before [the Meta Split](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/), I had the [Quorum badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum) but not the [Convention badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention).

So in order to earn the convention badge, do I need **10 new posts** with a score of 2 or more on meta.stackoverflow.com?

Or, do I need 10 posts *less the number of posts* that were on meta.stackoverflow.com, but are now on meta.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need 10 posts on *this* meta to earn Convention if you didn't previously earn it on the old MSO.